# How to detect and recognize complex shapes in the image using Python Image Processing?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, opencv3.0

I am new to StackOverflow.
I am trying to detecting shapes as per names and shapes in image of diamonds.[various shapes of diamond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZjOb.jpg). For shape detection purpose I used the program given at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/
Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
class ShapeDetector:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def detect(self, c):
        # initialize the shape name and approximate the contour
        shape = "unidentified"
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)

        # if the shape is a triangle, it will have 3 vertices
        if len(approx) == 3:
            shape = "triangle"
            # if the shape has 4 vertices, it is either a square or
            # a rectangle
        elif len(approx) == 4:
            # compute the bounding box of the contour and use the
            # bounding box to compute the aspect ratio
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            ar = w / float(h)
            # a square will have an aspect ratio that is approximately
            # equal to one, otherwise, the shape is a rectangle
            shape = "square" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "rectangle"
        # if the shape is a pentagon, it will have 5 vertices
        elif len(approx) == 5:
            shape = "pentagon"
        # otherwise, we assume the shape is a circle
        else:
            shape = "circle"
        # return the name of the shape
        return shape
# -----------------
image = cv2.imread(shape_image)
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=300)
ratio = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours in the thresholded image and initialize the
# shape detector
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
sd = ShapeDetector()

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour, then detect the name of the
    # shape using only the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
    cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
    shape = sd.detect(c)
    # multiply the contour (x, y)-coordinates by the resize ratio,
    # then draw the contours and the name of the shape on the image
    c = c.astype("float")
    c *= ratio
    c = c.astype("int")
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,     (255, 255, 255), 2)
print("The Shape of Object is: ", shape)
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But, I am unable to get perfect results for that. Is there any way to find out shapes like which are given in image.

Comment: You could try cv2.matchShapes() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317. Please show your exact code.  Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Anant, welcome to SO. This is not how question names are supposed to be written. These can be added as part of tags. Please read [ask] as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @ Akshay Sehgal, @fmw42: Thank you for your kind information.